# user not redirecting to website homepage after social login in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, wordpress, facebook-social-plugins

I am trying to inegrate my wordpress website with social media and have used a plugin called facebook all from http://wordpress.org/plugins/facebookall/ for this purpose, but after authentication the user is not redirected to his homepage, but when we reload the page the user is logged in. The issue is valid only in google chrome and works perfectly in Mozilla. Kindly help me ASAP.

Comment: Check the network tab in google chrome inspector (tools->developer's tool) and see if facebook is returning something. Then check if there's any error in the response.